# Why won't this value assign?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a member variable, `m_width`, that won't hold any value assigned to it. The relevant part of the class looks as follows:

```
class GPUFrame
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<void> m_deviceData;
    unsigned m_pitch = 0;
    unsigned m_width = 2; // testing if m_width will take any value
    unsigned m_height = 0;
    unsigned m_timestamp = 0; // time value in microseconds (absolute value is arbitrary)
    bool m_endOfStream = false; // signifies last frame in the stream

public:

    // make an entirely new allocation
    GPUFrame(unsigned imageWidth, unsigned imageHeight, unsigned allocationCols, unsigned allocationRows,
         unsigned timestamp, bool eos=false)
    {
        // initializer list was causing headaches
        m_pitch = 0;
        m_width = imageWidth;
        m_height = imageHeight;
        m_timestamp = timestamp;
        m_endOfStream = eos;

        // get space from CUDA
        void* newAllocation;
        cudaErr(cudaMallocPitch(&newAllocation, reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(&m_pitch), static_cast<size_t>(allocationCols), static_cast<size_t>(allocationRows)));

        // track allocation with the shared_ptr
        m_deviceData = std::shared_ptr<void>(newAllocation, [=](void* p){ cudaErrNE(cudaFree(p)); });

        std::cout << "imageWidth = " << imageWidth << ", m_width = " << m_width << std::endl;
    }

    // copy from given location
    GPUFrame(CUdeviceptr devPtr, unsigned pitch,
         unsigned imageWidth, unsigned imageHeight, unsigned allocationCols, unsigned allocationRows,
         unsigned timestamp, bool eos=false): GPUFrame(imageWidth, imageHeight, allocationCols, allocationRows, timestamp)
    {
        // copy into a more permanent chunk of memory allocated by above ctor
        cudaErr(cudaMemcpy2D(data(), m_pitch, reinterpret_cast<void*>(devPtr), pitch, allocationCols, allocationRows, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));
    }
}
```

The output I keep getting:

```
imageWidth = 1920, m_width = 0
```

I'm confused why `m_width` would even be 0, that doesn't even seem like an option. Does anyone have any clue as to what I'm doing wrong?

FWIW, I'm compiling with `g++-5` using the `--std=gnu++11` option. The full code is available at https://github.com/briantilley/computer-vision.

Comment: That `reinterpret_cast<size_t*>` looks extremely fishy.

Comment: What happens if you move the declaration of the `m_width` data member above that of `m_pitch`?

Comment: @T.C. Thank you! I moved the print statement above that line, and now I get the right behavior. I'll try to change things so I can get rid of the `reinterpret_cast` and see how that works. They told me it was dangerous to use, now I see why.

Comment: To understand what's going on, print `sizeof(unsigned)` and `sizeof(size_t)`. Then think about what happens if you have `m_pitch` and `m_width`, which are say 4 bytes each next to each other, and you lie to the compiler and tell it *here's a pointer to `m_pitch` which is of size 8 bytes* (actual sizes may be different on your platform)

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks for the explanation, I guess that portion of the `m_pitch` was being set to 0. After a bit of hunting, I see `size_t`is an `unsigned long long`, so y'all hit it directly on the head. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unsigned` is typically 4 bytes. `std::size_t`, on a 64-bit system, is typically 8 bytes.<sup>1</sup>

`cudaMallocPitch` writes to the thing pointed to by its second argument assuming that it's a `size_t`, but `m_pitch` is an `unsigned`, so it ends up clobbering `m_width`.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Usual disclaimers about unicorn systems apply.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! I changed `unsigned m_pitch` to `size_t m_pitch` and eliminated `reinterpret_cast` and the issue is gone.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
cudaMallocPitch(&newAllocation, reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(&m_pitch), static_cast<size_t>(allocationCols), static_cast<size_t>(allocationRows));
```

Will cause the pitch to be written to m_pitch.  This expects to write a size_t's worth of data to &m_pitch.

m_pitch is declared as "unsigned".  This is not necessarily the same size as a size_t.  If you output:

```
std::cout << sizeof(unsigned) << "\n" << sizeof(size_t)
```

Then I expect that you'll see "4" and "8".

So cudaMallocPitch will write 8 bytes, starting at &m_pitch.  This will overwrite the next field, which is m_width.

Changing the type of m_pitch to size_t should solve this.  You should also be able to remove the reinterpret_cast as well.

Comment: I discerned this from T.C.'s answer, but I'm glad yours will remain searchable for the future. This was the solution, and I'd +1 if I could. Thank you!